# How to pull a single (or few) packages from Debian testing to Debian oldstable?

Tags: debian, testing

Is this possible? I'm looking to install specific packages from Debian testing (buster) into Debian oldstable (jessie).

Answer (score 1):

First, add the testing branch to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing-updates main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main
```

Then, pin testing in `/etc/apt/preferences` so that packages won't get pulled in automatically.

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=testing
Pin-Priority: -2
```

Now, when you want a package from testing, specify the target release manually. Be careful not to let half your system get upgraded.

```
# apt-get install -t testing ...
```