# Install phpMyAdmin 5.2.1 with apt on Debian 11 with php8.1

Tags: apt, php, phpmyadmin

`apt install phpmyadmin` on Debian 11 installs the old versin 5.0.4 that is not php8.1 compatible.

How do I install the latest version via apt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian stable (bookworm) has the latest `phpmyadmin` package in it ([see here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=phpmyadmin)). So first, add the testing branch to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stable-security main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable-updates main
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stable main
```

Then, pin testing in `/etc/apt/preferences` so that packages won't get pulled in automatically.

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=stable
Pin-Priority: -2
```

Now, when you want a package from testing, specify the target release manually. Be careful not to let half your system get upgraded.

```
apt update
apt-get install -t stable phpmyadmin
```

This will install Version 5.2.1 over 5.0.4

source https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439078/20661 by  @user277591